# Radial Limit of a conformal isomorphism - making domain bounded

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, functions

I'm currently working through a proof regarding the radial limit of an conformal iso $\psi :\mathbb{D} \rightarrow U$ - it is section 15.3 of Milnor's Dynamics in One Complex Variable (which can be found here https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201272).

I understand the majority of the proof, but am unsure on how we are able reduce to the bounded case. For $\psi:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow U$ a conformal isomorphism, this is what Milnor puts:

[image]

Why does composing by a linear fractional map make it bounded, and why must $\psi(D)$ omit at least two values. If theres any way someone could break down what is happening here, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks